# English transliteration of the Persian word for werewolf?

Tags: translation, persian, werewolves

I have found that the Persian word for werewolf is (گرگینه) which the closest English transliteration I can find is "grgynh". Does anyone know of better transliteration, that lends itself to being pronounced more easily? Or an older term for werewolf from this region, like Avestian? I have found varka as Avestian for wolf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may seem odd, but I'm answering my own question. The transliteration answer for  (گرگینه)  is gorgine. I found the answer here: https://www.wordsense.eu/werewolf/ and the audio pronunciation here:
https://www.languagedrops.com/word/en/english/persian/translate/werewolf/

Comment: Accept your own answer too!  That's also allowed.

Comment: As a word, it might be related to "gorgon"? https://www.etymonline.com/word/gorgon#etymonline_v_9063

Comment: Thank you, mrcasals. It's actual root word is گرگ  (pronounced gorg or gurg) which is Persian for wolf. The older Persian language, Avestian, word for wolf is varka, which did spread into norse as vargr (wolf) and werewolf like creatures the vrykolakas (Greek) also known as Vârcolak (Slavic) though considered something in-between a werwolf and vampire. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrykolakas